# Meteor app doesn't run

Tags: meteor

On running Telescope, I get the following error:

```
    /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:206
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: DDP disconnected
    at Object.Future.wait (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:326:15)
    at _.extend.apply (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/service-connection.js:107:31)
    at _.extend.call (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/service-connection.js:84:17)
    at Object.exports.callPackageServer (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:57:20)
    at loadRemotePackageData (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:129:30)
    at getSomeData (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:244:20)
    at _updateServerPackageData (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:296:7)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:201:15
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:247:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:240:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:238:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:229:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:228:19)
    at Object.exports.updateServerPackageData (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/package-client.js:200:16)
    at _.extend._refresh (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:181:40)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:147:14
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:323:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:316:34
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:314:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.enterJob (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:300:26)
    at _.extend.refresh (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:143:18)
    at _.extend._recordOrRefresh (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog-base.js:104:26)
    at _.extend.getReleaseVersion (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/catalog.js:242:17)
    at Object.release.load (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/release.js:245:41)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:820:23
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:247:13
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:240:29
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:238:18
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:229:23
    at _.extend.withValue (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
    at Object.capture (/home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:228:19)
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/main.js:819:35
    - - - - -
    at /home/faisal/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.dxlff3++os.linux.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.linux.x86_64/tools/service-connection.js:69:26
    at packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:100
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Function._.each._.forEach (packages/underscore/underscore.js:105)
    at _.extend._cleanup (packages/ddp/stream_client_nodejs.js:99)
    at _.extend._lostConnection (packages/ddp/stream_client_common.js:201)
    at _.extend._lostConnection (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:955)
    at self._heartbeat.Heartbeat.onTimeout [as _onTimeout] (packages/ddp/livedata_connection.js:1047)
    at _.extend._heartbeatTimeoutFired (packages/ddp/heartbeat.js:79)
    at _.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56)
    at packages/meteor/timers.js:6
    at runWithEnvironment (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108)
```

I searched on the web and found that it is the slow internet problem. But, I can watch youtube, and do other internet based stuff properly. Anyone there with a solution? :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are having some DDP, probably you have some connection problems if not, take a look on this issue on github

https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/2789

also if you say you can watch youtube and other stuff and its not internet problem you should unnistall/install meteor again